# I need an event fired after successful export on DataTables 1.10

Tags: datatables, tabletools, datatables-1.10

I'm using DataTables 1.10.4 and I would like to make an action, like a javascript function, after a successful Excel export.

Is it possible, since the button is using Adobe Flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [**documentation**](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options#fnComplete). Below an example with Excel-button :

```js
...
"oTableTools": {
     "aButtons": [
         {
             "sExtends": "xls",
             "fnComplete": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash, sFlash ) {
                 alert( 'Excel-export complete' );
             }
         }
     ]
 }
...
```